# How to remove unwanted space in header after tabularx

Tags: header-footer, tabularx

When I set width of the table below width of textwidth for example to value 300px it is ok but when I set it exactly on textwidth a space after table appear. How do I delete this space? The spacing between header and main text is set to 0px.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,pdftex,czech]{book}

%nezbytné balíčky
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % kódování písma
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % znaková sada
\usepackage[czech]{babel}       % česká tipografie
\usepackage{lipsum}             % text na vyplnění
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % uživatelsky definované záhlaví a zápatí
\usepackage{geometry}           %  
\geometry{a4paper,
    includeheadfoot,
    bindingoffset=1cm,
    left=2.5cm,
    right=2.5cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
    headheight=2cm,
    headsep=0cm}    % využití A4 stránky a nastavení okrajů (u vazby bude širší) 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{
    \begin{tabularx}{300px}{@{}X r@{}}
        \skola, \fakulta & acad. year: \rok \\ \hline
        \katedra & \autor 
    \end{tabularx} 
}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\linespread{1.1} % řádkování

\begin{document}
\newpage 
~ 
\vfill 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{ddd}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,pdftex,czech]{book}

%nezbytné balíčky
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % kódování písma
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % znaková sada
\usepackage[czech]{babel}       % česká tipografie
\usepackage{lipsum}             % text na vyplnění
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % uživatelsky definované záhlaví a zápatí
\usepackage{geometry}           %  
\geometry{a4paper,
    includeheadfoot,
    bindingoffset=1cm,
    left=2.5cm,
    right=2.5cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
    headheight=2cm,
    headsep=0cm}    % využití A4 stránky a nastavení okrajů (u vazby bude širší) 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[C]{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X r@{}}
        \skola, \fakulta & acad. year: \rok \\ \hline
        \katedra & \autor 
    \end{tabularx} 
}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\linespread{1.1} % řádkování

\begin{document}
\newpage 
~ 
\vfill 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{ddd}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a complete compilable example, that we can play with.

Comment: you are adding a space before and a space after the tabularx, so there is not room for `\textwidth`  comment out the ends of lines, and end of line is a space.

Comment: How can I delete or remove these spaces?